# How to get type discriminator for class?

Tags: c#, mdriven, model-driven-development

In MDriven I'd like to get the type discriminator for a modeled class at runtime. I thought I had done it before, but can't seem to find it and can't figure it out.

I mean the integer that appears first in the external id string, e.g. "72" in external id "72!i64!12345678".

I need to get the discriminator based on C# type, i.e. typeof(MyClass), without having any object instance available. This makes it impossible to extract the discriminator from the external id string, because I have no such string available at the time and can't create one.

I'm using `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType` so the external id's type discriminator matches the type discriminator in the database, in case that matters. But how do I lookup the discriminator for a type, in runtime?

Comment: `string td = id.Split('!')[0];`

Comment: @CodingYoshi: No, please read my clarification. The purpose is to create an external id string from the numeric id number, the id type "i64" (known) and the discriminator number, which I need to look up somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding source code for `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType` I was able to create this solution:

```
public static string GetClassDiscriminator<T>(this IEcoServiceProvider sp)
{
    IEcoTypeSystem typeSys = sp.GetEcoService<ITypeSystemService>().TypeSystem;
    IClass cls = typeSys.AllClasses.Cast<IClass>().First(c => c.ObjectType == typeof(T));
    if (sp.GetEcoService<IExternalIdService>() is Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType)
    {
        ORMappingDefinition mapping = ((PersistenceMapperDb)DiamondsPMP.Instance.PersistenceMapper).EffectiveRunTimeMappingProvider.Mapping;
        if (mapping == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(PersistenceStringRes.MappingProviderNotInitialized);
        ClassDefinition classdef = mapping.Classes[typeSys.AllClasses[0].Name];
        if (classdef.Discriminators.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(PersistenceStringRes.RootclassHasNoDiscriminatorDefined);
        DiscriminatorDef discriminator = classdef.Discriminators.Cast<DiscriminatorDef>().First();
        DiscriminatorValue discvalue = discriminator.DiscriminatorValuesByClassId(cls.InternalIndex);
        if (discvalue == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(PersistenceStringRes.ClassHasNoDiscriminatorValueDefined);
        if (discvalue.IsFinal && cls.SubTypes.Count > 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(PersistenceStringRes.DiscriminatorIsFinal);
        return discvalue.Value;
    }
    else
        return cls.InternalIndex.ToString();
}
```

The `sp.GetEcoService<IExternalIdService>() is Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType` is required in my case, because in my unit tests i use `PersistenceMapperMemory`, which uses the index in `TypeSystem.AllClasses` as type discriminator, which is also the value returned by `IClass.InternalIndex`.

I also note that `IExternalIdService.ObjectForIdSeperateClassInfo()` is buggy. It acts as if `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl` is being used, returning an `IObjectInstance` of the wrong type (using the class' index in `TypeSystem.AllClasses`).

Comment: Great digging! I will fix the issue with ObjectForIdSeperateClassInfo when using the ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType service. It is now overridden to use the correct db-based Discriminator value

Answer (score 0):

The discriminator 72 is also the index in the TypeService list of Classes.

```
IClass umlClass = (IClass)TypeSystem.AllClasses[72];
```

Comment: Note - new builds support adding the discriptor name instead of the number when sending in identities: TheRealClassName!i64!12345678

This is more robust for models that change (all models change) - at least if the number is stored by third party.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to build the externalid string, so I would rather need the opposite: `TypeSystem.AllClasses.IndexOf(umlClass)`.

Comment: Also, would that be `TheCSharpClassName!i64!12345678` or `ModeledClassName!i64!12345678`?

Comment: @KjellRilbe - the c# name, the one we call RuntimeName

Comment: Is your answer valid for `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType`?

Comment: For most practical purposes yes - if you have advanced ORMapping implementations you may have multiple discriminator values on a single class - this will offset the db discriminator against the class-index

Comment: Picking up this thread, trying `sp.GetEcoService<ITypeSystemService>().TypeSystem.AllClasses[17].ModeledName` because `ECO_TYPE = 17` in the database, I don't get the class I want. I get something completely different. I do not have any advanced mappings, but I do have two packages (ASP provider + my own stuff). Any suggestions?

Comment: Retrieving all entries from `TypeSystem` as well as the table `ECO_TYPE` shows no correlation whatsoever between the `ECO_TYPE` values used by `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType` and the indices in `TypeSystem`. So as far as I can see your answer simply is not true for `Eco.Services.Impl.ExternalIdServiceImpl_DbType`. My question remains unanswered.

Comment: By the way `TypeSystem.AllClasses` is an `ICollection`, which doesn't support `IndexOf()`. In fact, if item indices are relevant in any way, it probably should be an `IList` and not an `ICollection`. Collections are intended for unordered collections of items.

Comment: @KjellRilbe - it will be the Name==RuntimeName and not the ModelName (that may contain national chars)